# how to hide hidden value from source code in html?

Tags: html

In my html I'm using hidden value as :`<input type="hidden" value="secure" name="first">` but the problem is when I see in browser console value is displaying .How to hide this?

Answer (score 2):

The browser belongs to the visitor. You can't give the browser anything without giving it to the visitor as well.

If you don't want to visitor to have access to data, then never give it to the browser in the first place.

Keep the data on the server and send the browser a session token instead.

Comment: Nice how we posted mostly identical replies in literally exactly the same second.

Comment: @ThazAhammad no, because there is no generic solution. It completely depends on your [real problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) what the correct one is in your case. Ask a new more elaborate question, or [start reading here](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).

Comment: @ThazAhammad — http://search.cpan.org/~jjnapiork/Catalyst-Plugin-Session-0.39/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/Session.pm (obviously this depends on you using a particular programming language and MVC framework, you probably want to start by selecting a server side programming framework and then looking for a general session tutorial for it)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The whole point of a client/server based setup, like 'the web' is by definition, is that everything you transmit to the client can be read by any client.

If you need to secure data from the end user, keep it on the server side. There are a myriad of possible solutions for this, like sessions, cookies and preshared keys, to sync serverside storage with the client.

Comment: Niels,I used in servlet as like this :out.println("<input type="hidden" value="secure" name="+session.id+">"); though it is showing in browser source page

Comment: That's because you're printing it to the HTML output so the browser can actually act on it. You seem to be missing the point of how the web works, might want to read up on it.